# How to Disable Ubuntu Phone "auto dim" function?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, screen, brightness, phone

Is there a way to disable the auto dim function of the Ubuntu Phone (14.10 r22)?
Even though I can disable the auto-brightness function and set the screen timeout to 10 minutes (or never) the screen of my phone is dimmed after a minute of inactivity - meaning NO TOUCH of the screen... This is annoying when watching youtube.

Answer (score 0):

*Preparation:* If you haven't done so already, install the Terminal app.

In the Terminal write:

```
$ dconf write /com/ubuntu/touch/system/dim-timeout "@u 0"
```

The `dim-timeout` Key wants an *unsigned int* as a value. That's what the `@u` is for. The number stands for the seconds after the screen is dimmed (0 = infinite).

(Since the setting is stored for the local user (phablet), it's not nessecary to make the root file system writeable.)

(Tested on the Ubuntu tablet, with Ubuntu Touch 15.04.)

Answer (score -2):

The auto dim is controlled by the donf key `/com/ubuntu/touch/system/dim-timeout`. You can set the timeout to 0 (= infinite) by executing this command in a terminal:

```
$ dconf write /com/ubuntu/touch/system/dim-timeout 0
```

The dconf database for the default user `phablet` is used for brightness control, not the root database, so do you should execute the command as phablet.

---

The above should work, but I had to remount the root file system writable and play with the brightness in the system settings app until it worked, but I don't know why or what happened exactly. Remounting the root file system writable is done (as root).

```
# remount -o remount,rw /
```

You can lock it against writing again by rebooting. Try this anyway, to see if the fix stuck.